# C++ deque throwing Segfaults

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, deque

I have some code from a project which doesn't seem to be working.

I am trying to make a deque (of a struct) which is a static member of a class.
The skeleton/basic code is as follows (I have retained all datatypes - my_typedef_fn is a data type got by typedef-ing a function pointer) :

1.h file :

```
class A {
    struct Bstruct {
        char * b_name;
        my_typedef_fn b_func;
    }
    static std::deque<Bstruct> a_deque;
    static void func();
}
```

1.cpp file :

```
std::deque<A::Bstruct> A::a_deque;
void A::func(char * name, my_typedef_fn fn) {
    a_deque.push_front((Bstruct) {name, fn} ); // <<<< segfault !
}
```

From my understanding
 - The .h file just declares the stuff (as usual)
 - The first line in the .cpp initializes the static member a_deque
 - The function func adds stuff to the deque using push_back

But I get a Segmentation Error at the line where push_front is called (found this using gdb).

Also, when I print a_deque.size() before push_front I get 4294967264 before the SEGFAULT
And when I count the number of elements in deque using a for loop :

```
int counter = 0
for( std::deque<Bstruct> it = a_deque.begin(); it != a_deque.end(); it++, counter++ );
```

my counter shows 0 elements to be in the

So, I do not understand why I get a segfault nor why the .size() is a large garbage number

-- EDIT 1 --
Adding the way the functions are called :

2.cpp

```
#include "1.h"
void fn1() { 
    // some code
}
A::func("abc", fn1);
```

It is complied with the commands :

```
g++ -c -w -fpermissive -o 1.o 1.cpp
g++ -c -w -fpermissive -o 2.o 2.cpp
g++ -o final 1.o 2.o
```

Comment: Why not use `std::string` instead of `char*`?  Given that, what is `name` and how does it get its value?  Using char* for string data isn't as innocuous as it looks.

Comment: Your syntax for constructing an element is weird. Did you mean `Bstruct{name, fn}`? I actually don’t know off the top of my head what your code does, or why it even compiles, but it’s probably not what you want.

Comment: Are you calling the code from a constructor of a global, which could cause `a_deque` to be accessed before it's had a chance to initialise itself? And please fix such syntactic nonsenses as `A:BStruct`.

Comment: This code is something I did not write - It is from an old project (2002) which I am trying to run. @PaulMcKenzie : The char * gets it value from a const character ... the function is called as : func("abc", fn1);

Comment: @Angew, I have fixed the A:Bstruct, sorry for the confusion. The "func" is being called in global (in another .cpp file - let's call is 2.cpp). I just went through the Makefile, and here's how it does it - It compiles this .cpp file using the flags : -c -w -fpermissive and compiles the 2.cpp file with the same flags. Then it links all the .o files into a final file (like : g++ -o final 1.o 2.o 3.o) which I run. So, how do I check whether the function "func" is called at the correct time ?

Comment: What does "being called in global" mean? Can you add the call site to the question?

Comment: @Angew - I have added it. Also, an edit from earlier - func is also static

Comment: I am wondering if this has something to do with static initialization of a_deque. If the construction of deque() completed, I don't see why the size should return MAX_INT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normally not possible to simply call a function in global scope, like you're showing in `2.cpp`. But you mentioned the code is old, so maybe it's a pre-standard thing, or an extension.

Anyway, you've shown the function is being called in `2.cpp`, while the static data member `a_deque` is defined in `1.cpp`. This means you're probably falling prey to *static initialisation order fiasco.* Globals (such as static data members, and apparently this weird free-standing function call as well) are initialised/executed in order they appear within one translation unit (= `.cpp` file), but their order across translation units is unspecified.

Which means it's perfectly possible for `A::func()` to access `a_deque` before the constructor of `a_deque` has run, which could very possibly lead to a segfault (as the internal data members of the deque have zero or possibly even random values).

To fix this, you'll have to get rid of this situation somehow. One option would be to move all global code which can access `a_deque` into `1.cpp` and place it after the definition of `a_deque`.

An alternative would be to replace `a_deque` with a function-scope static variable, which is guaranteed to be initialised before first use:

1.h

```
class A {
    struct Bstruct {
        char * b_name;
        my_typedef_fn b_func;
    }
    static std::deque<BStruct>& a_deque();
    static void func();
}
```

1.cpp

```
#include "1.h"

std::deque<A::BStruct>& A::a_deque()
{
  static std::deque<BStruct> d;
  return d;
}

void A::func(char * name, my_typedef_fn fn) {
    a_deque().push_front((Bstruct) {name, fn} ); // <<<< hopefully no more segfault
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense ! This code is essentially used to relate a bunch of functions with some names - so a specific function can be called when a user gives a particular name. And there are tens of these functions - which are very large and modular on their own (spanning across 7-8 files) ... Can you suggest some other way ? DO you think there may exist a flag in gcc to resolve this ? Or does the order in which I use the 1.o or 2.o in the last step of compiling matter ? I do know it was working in 2002 :P I would rather not rework the whole structure

Comment: @AJK I've added an alternative solution which should work regardless of global initialisation order.